# simple use of jquery .css, .height, .width breaking in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am trying to use jquery to resize a div containing a 100% height/width image in an asp.net page.  I have some code that works fine as a simple html page.  Here it is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Image Resize Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SizeSelect").change(function() {
        var newDim = $(this).val();
        $("div.pillContainer").height(newDim);
        $("div.pillContainer").width(newDim);
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">    
    div.pillContainer {
    width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        display: block;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    div.pillContainer img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="pillContainer"><img src="http://www.marvinandshea.com/Images/thumbs/friends_thumbs/friends%20(24).JPG" /></div>

<b>Size:</b> <select id="SizeSelect" name="SizeSelect" >
<option value="50 px">Small</option>
<option value="70 px">Medium</option>
<option value="90 px">Large</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason, as soon as I put this exact code in an .aspx page in between form tags runat=server, the re-sizing quits working.  To be specific, here's my broken aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyMediHealth.Interface.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Image Resize Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SizeSelect").change(function() {
        var newDim = $(this).val();
        $("div.pillContainer").height(newDim);
        $("div.pillContainer").width(newDim);
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    div.pillContainer {
    width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        display: block;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    div.pillContainer img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div class="pillContainer"><img src="http://www.marvinandshea.com/Images/thumbs/friends_thumbs/friends%20(24).JPG" /></div>

<b>Size:</b> <select id="SizeSelect" name="SizeSelect" >
    <option value="50 px">Small</option>
    <option value="70 px">Medium</option>
    <option value="90 px">Large</option>
</select>

</form>
</body>
```

Anybody know why it's not working and how to fix it?

Comment: If you put the same `<!DOCTYPE>` in your static HTML page, does it still work?

Comment: check in the firebug if the jquery is loaded or not ?? breaking means the page is broken or jquery is not working

Comment: one more difference is ..in asp.net page you have a doctype but in normal html you don't have doctype

Comment: Interesting, removing the doctype does fix it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A better question is: why is it working at all in either version. :)

You are sending "50 px" (or whatever) to jQuery's height function.  Try just sending a number instead by changing your options to:

```
<option value="50">Small</option>
<option value="70">Medium</option>
<option value="90">Large</option>
```

Changing this fixed it for me in ASP.net. (it didn't work before, like you said)

I haven't tested your HTML only version to see why it works.

**EDIT:** For the record, I can't get your other version to work in JSFiddle either. I think you changed it before you ported it to ASP.net and didn't realize you broke it?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this for me.  When I read the jquery documentation for height at http://api.jquery.com/height/, it says "When calling .height(value), the value can be either a string (number and unit) or a number. If only a number is provided for the value, jQuery assumes a pixel unit."  So, I don't think the presence or lack of units is the issue.  But Frédéric Hamidi's removal-of-doctype solution works.

Comment: Try multiple browsers.  Removing it wasn't effective for me.

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me, though you are missing the  closing tag in your .aspx code block.

Comment: What browser did you try it in? I haven't seen his examples work unmodified in any browser.

Comment: IE 9 doesn't accept the space, unless you use compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is no space between a value and it's unit. Remove the spaces, and it works:

```
<select id="SizeSelect" name="SizeSelect" >
  <option value="50px">Small</option>
  <option value="70px">Medium</option>
  <option value="90px">Large</option>
</select>
```

It will also work if you remove both the space and the unit, as clifgriffin suggests. The `width` and `height` methods will add `px` if the value is only digits.

When you use this in a page without a doctype, it's rendered in quirks mode and the rules are more relaxed. The space between the value and the unit is still not allowed, but some browsers will use the value and assume the unit `px`, and ignore what's after the space.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  For me, as long as I still have the doctype declaration, nothing works.  However, if I remove the doctype, any of these variations (with or without the space, with or without the units) seems to work fine .

Comment: @Marvin: I copied your code above except the page directive, removed the spaces in the values and tried it in different browsers. It works in Firefox 3.6.12, IE 9 (normal and compatibility mode), Opera 10.63 and Safari 4.0.5.